# Inserting HTML code within PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I need to put some cobinated HTML PHP code in the second parameter of the `str_replace` function in CodeIgniter.

```
<a href="<?=base_url();?>pages/articles/<?=str_replace($replace_simbols, '-', $category);?>.html" ></a>

<dt><?=character_limiter($categoryEntry1[2],110).'<a href="NEED TO PUT HERE ATRIBUTE FROM FIRST a href" >'.'<img class="read_more" src="/img/read_more.png" alt="read more" title="Read more..." /></a>'?></dt>

$replace_symbols , var contain (some symbols).
```

How can I do this?

Comment: cant you `urlencode(thestring)`?

Comment: Thank you mithunsatheesh for editing. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just put everything in a variable? Btw since when does codeigniter have .html extension

```
$href_link = base_url() . "pages/articles/" . str_replace($replace_simbols, '-', $category);
<a href="<?=$href_link;?>.html" ></a>

 <dt><?=character_limiter($categoryEntry1[2],110).'<a href="<?=$href_link;?>.html">'.'<img class="read_more" src="/img/read_more.png" alt="read more" title="Read more..." /></a>'?></dt>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$href = base_url() . "pages/articles/" . str_replace($replace_simbols, '-', $category) . ".html";

<a href="<?php echo $href;?>"></a>

<dt><?=character_limiter($categoryEntry1[2],110).'<a href="' . $href . '" >'.'<img class="read_more" src="/img/read_more.png" alt="read more" title="Read more..." /></a>'?></dt>
```